# How to get the Custom settings list?

Tags: customsetting

I want to get all of the custom settings in a list and then according to the custom setting i want to build a query?
Can someone suggest how i can do that.

For eg: i have a custom setting as A1, A2,A3. I want to do something like:
`List<A1> A1list = A1.getall().values();` I have to repeat the same code for all. How can i optimise this, by using something like `sObject.getGlobaldescribe()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Custom Setting were named Custom_Setting__c, you could do the following:

```
List<Custom_Setting__c> customSettings = new List<Custom_Setting__c>();
for (Custom_Setting__c customSetting : [SELECT Name FROM Custom_Setting__c])
{
    customSettings.add(customSetting);
}
```

**However**, since they are all different Custom Settings you would need to do separate queries, which would be more expensive than

```
List<Custom_Setting_A__c> listA = Custom_Setting_A__c.getAll().values();
List<Custom_Setting_B__c> listB = Custom_Setting_B__c.getAll().values();
List<Custom_Setting_C__c> listC = Custom_Setting_C__c.getAll().values();
```

That's about as lightweight as it will get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I want to remove the section "List<Custom_Setting_A__c> listA = Custom_Setting_A__c.getAll().values();
List<Custom_Setting_B__c> listB = Custom_Setting_B__c.getAll().values();
List<Custom_Setting_C__c> listC = Custom_Setting_C__c.getAll().values();" i.e. specifiying the name of the custom setting.getall.values(). That means i want ot make it more generic. Is this not possible.

Comment: No. They're essentially separate objects. It's like if you were trying to combine a query for Opportunities and Contacts, except you can't even use lookups to get around query limitations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly round-about way of getting the list of Custom Settings using the metadata api.  In this example, i use the REST api to access it.

You can get you all of the objects in your org.  Each type of Custom Setting is saved as a different custom object definition.  So, if you iterate through this list, only look at those objects that have the 'customSetting' property = true.  Here's an abbreviated version of how I do it in Groovy with the REST API (some sections omitted).  You can find documentation about the response in the [REST API Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/dome_describeGlobal.htm)

```
def conn = new SfRestConnection(username, password, clientId, clientSecret, SfRestConnection.SfAuthenticationEndpointForProd)
conn.login()

//as an example: https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/ 
def results = conn.get('sobjects', null, null)
for(def obj in results.sobjects)
{
    if(obj.customSetting)
        println obj.name
}
```